# Linking to Google Search in href

Tags: php

I am dynamically creating a table, and I'd like to display the title of the books to be links to a Google search of the title. I have looked at many solutions here, but all suggest something like this:

`"<td><a href='http://google.com/q={$title}'>'$title'</a></td>";`

```
echo "<TR>";
echo "<TD><a href='http://google.com/q={$title}'>$title</a></TD>";
echo "</TR>";
```

But I cannot get this to work since `//` keeps getting recognized as a comment. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: are you trying to echo this?

Comment: If the `//` is enclosed in double quotes, it won't be parsed as a comment. Something else must be happening.

Comment: @MehemmedRustemzade Yes, I am trying to echo it out.

Comment: can you show your complete code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
echo "<TR>";
echo "<TD><a href='http://google.com/?gws_rd=cr,ssl#q={$title}'>$title</a></TD>";
echo "</TR>";
```

it is not perfect way to search, use google search script for best result.
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/implementingsearchbox